# How to install textatistic package

Tags: python, conda

I want to install `textatistic` package on my `Jupyter/ Anaconda/ Windows64` platform.

I tried to run `conda install -c conda-forge textatistic` *from Anaconda command prompt* as an administrator.

It is throwing up error - `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`.

Appreciate inputs.

Comment: Are you sure it is available as a Conda package?

Comment: pip install textatistic,from textatistic import Textatistic

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself and it gave the same error. I then followed the instructions from the error:

```
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

According to https://anaconda.org, the package `textatastic` doesn't exist.